# How to relabel a Pandas Dataframe starting at 1 with RangeIndex when stop is not known?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bioinformatics

So I'm building software that takes large csv files of amino acid data and converts them to a pandas DataFrame. I need to relabel the columns 1-n. Is there a way to do this when the stop value is not known?  I've tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8', header=None)
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=3000, step=1)
```

I always end up with a length mismatch error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2902 elements, new values have 2999 elements
```

Surely there a simple way to anonymize the stop value so that different sequences can be loaded and relabeled properly?

Comment: Imo it is not clear what you're asking or trying to achieve, because you talk about _columns 1-n_ which should be renamed but in your code you are trying to create a new index (which is the "labels" of the _rows_) - although you should have a nice index after the import; do you simply want a one-based index instead of a zero-based one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are way overthinking it. Since you index started at 0 and you now want to change it to 1-based, simply add 1 to the index:

```
df.index += 1
```